# Ubuntu 12.10 GNOME Commander change connection

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and GNOME Commander 1.2.8.15.
In the Commander I can not use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to change left/right connection. When I press either key combinations, the menu pane gets activated, but nothing happens.

I have installed CCSM, where I have modified key bindings at GNOME compatibility and also at Unity.

Do you have any ideas, what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortcut you described above is not available. Just have a look here:
http://gcmd.github.io/keys.html.

Maybe you mean <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>? These shortcuts are working in my case. By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> a small window opens where I can choose the new connection in the left pannel.